# ExtJs 6 Calendar week and day events

Tags: javascript, extjs, calendar, sencha-touch, extjs6-classic

How can add `eventClick` listeners on Calendar `Week` and `day` views. I have added listener on `Month` view and its working fine but i have no events on Week and Day Views. Is there a way that i can add events to those views as well. Or any work around.

I don't want to include whole `extension` for that either.

```
xtype: 'panel',
title: 'Calendar',
layout: 'fit',
width: 1200,
height: 600,
items: [{
    xtype: 'calendar',
    views: {
        day: {
            addForm: null,
            editForm: null,
            listeners: {
                eventtap: 'onEventClick' //this doesn't work 
            }
        },
        week: {
            addForm: null,
            editForm: null,
            listeners: {
                eventtap: 'onEventClick' //this doesn't work 
            }
        },
        month: {
            addForm: null,
            editForm: null,
            listeners: {
                eventtap: 'onEventClick' // this works
            }
        }
    },
    bind: {
        store: '{calendars}'
    }
}]
```

The default Add and Edit form are working but i want to open my own window on event click to show just the details about the event. Not the window editable or addable windows that is the detault. 
Is there a work around for adding `event click` for `Week` and `Day` view just like `Month view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a **bug/issue** in the source code of ExtJs Calendar package. 
Go to

> ext/packages/calendar/src/calendar/view/days.js

at line `1436` change function `onEventTap` with this code:

```
    onEventTap: function(e) {
        var event = this.getEvent(e);
        this.fireEvent('eventtap', this, {
            event: event
        });
        this.showEditForm(event);
    },
```

Comment: it's not good to modify the ExtJS code directly, rather you can override it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which is working for me fine.

```
{
        xtype: 'calendar',
        flex: 1,
        reference: 'customMainCalendarRef',
        border: false,
        layout: 'border',
        timezoneOffset: 0,
        manageHeight: false,
        createButtonPosition: 'titleBar',
        createButton: {
            xtype: 'button',
            region: 'center',
            hidden: true
        },
        views: {
            month: {
                xtype: 'calendar-month',
                region: 'west',
                //id:'tasksMonthViewId',
                width: 150,
                label: 'Month',
                view: {
                    xtype: 'calendar-monthview',
                    addForm: null,
                    editForm: null,
                    firstDayOfWeek: 1,
                    listeners: {
                        eventtap: 'onCalendarmonthviewEventtap',
                        select: 'onTaskCalendarmonthviewSelect',
                        valuechange: 'onCalendarmonthviewValueChange'
                    }
                },
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: 'onCalendarmonthAfterRender',
                    added: 'onMonthViewAdded'
                }
            },
            week: {
                xtype: 'calendar-week',
                region: 'east',
                //id:'tasksWeekViewId',
                width: 150,
                label: 'Week',
                view: {
                    xtype: 'calendar-weekview',
                    timeRenderer: function(hour, formatted, firstInGroup) {
                        return '';
                    },
                    addForm: null,
                    editForm: null,
                    firstDayOfWeek: 1,
                    listeners: {
                        eventtap: 'onCalendarweekviewEventtap'
                    }
                }
            },
            day: {
                xtype: 'calendar-day',
                //id:'tasksDayViewId',
                region: 'north',
                height: 150,
                label: 'Day',
                view: {
                    xtype: 'calendar-dayview',
                    timeRenderer: function(hour, formatted, firstInGroup) {
                        return '';
                    },
                    addForm: null,
                    editForm: null,
                    listeners: {
                        eventtap: 'onCalendardayviewEventtap'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```